# how to store data from all datagridview in one row of database (or different approach?)

Tags: c#, datagridview, load, save

I am making a program to create offers for my clients. Everything is working fine. But I try to make it store a data from offers in some kind of database. The program makes an offer as a pdf. But at sometimes I need to load an offer to make some changes.
I have a datagridview with 7 columns and some textboxes with clients data. What I need to store this client data and all rows from an offer. The problem I have is that there are different numbers of rows in datagridview so I cannot make it to store in SQL database I use.
How can I solve this? Should I use csv file? xls? or is there some other trick?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understood the question correctly, but why you can't store this data in multiple database rows with the same OfferID? Why do you want to have this in one DB row? After that you can create selection like:

```
Select * From Table where OfferID = some_id
```

From my perspective it doesn't matter that it would be hold in database in several rows.

Comment: You mean that i should store all rows from datagridview as separate rows in sql database and recognize that they are from same offer by adding a offer number as part of each of the row? That is quite good idea:D Ill try that

Comment: @Łukasz - Exactly like you said, I think it's the best solution.

Comment: Ok did some testing and I can store and load an offer from database. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is to serialize (ie. XmlSerializer) your gridview and store it as one string